# Two React Native application running simultaneously on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm having trouble when drawing two React Application simultaneously on iOS.
Something when a click on button from application 1, the button from application 2 is also triggered.
It seems to me that both components have the same reactTagId and it is messing the whole thing.

It's not possible to have two application (Rootview) sharing a screen? Something like a big screen shared in two frames, each one with a different application.

I did that on Android, using two ReactInstanceManger and it works.
However, it doesn't work on iOS.

So te bug is: clicking in button 1 from ReactApp one and have button 1 and button 2 triggered.